# Executing requests in ruby using net/http

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use net/http to get a response for API call based on an old library I dug up https://github.com/jurisgalang/facebook/blob/master/lib/facebook/graph-object.rb#L22

```
require 'net/http'

API_HOST       = "graph.facebook.com"
API_BASE_URL   = "https://#{API_HOST}"
path           = "/boo"

uri            = URI.parse "#{API_BASE_URL}#{path}"
http           = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
res            = http.get(uri.request_uri, nil)
```

The `uri` ends up as `<URI::HTTPS:0x0000010091fc48 URL:https://graph.facebook.com/boo>`

This results in

> NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass

I assumed it is because `dest` argument is obsolete: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-get

So I did it without

```
res            = http.get(uri.request_uri)
```

Which results in

> NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for

```
#<URI::HTTPS:0x0000010091fc48 URL:https://graph.facebook.com/boo>
```

How can one request a response using net/http and http.get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just at a very quick glance of [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-get), the second argument to `get` is a hash, and you're passing nil, see:

```
http.get(uri.request_uri, nil)
```

Your second attempt should be OK, though I did find that with my setup (ruby 1.9.3 and MacPorts' openssl library) that Net::HTTP was rejecting Facebook's ssl certificate (I was getting "Connection reset by peer". The following code snippet worked for me:

```
require 'net/http'

API_HOST       = "graph.facebook.com"
API_BASE_URL   = "https://#{API_HOST}"
path           = "/boo"

uri            = URI.parse "#{API_BASE_URL}#{path}"
http           = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl   = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
res            = http.get(uri.request_uri)
puts res.body
```

Note that I'm not verifying the SSL certificate, which is a potential security problem. As a proof of concept, however, this snippet worked for me - so hopefully this will give you a good data point in your debugging effort.

Comment: Alright thanks I will have to figure out what to do with that SSL problem then

Comment: I've searched the highest mountains and the deepest oceans for this answer. Thankyou!

Comment: what if my api is asking for username and password ? how I can handle that? in my case when my api pop a window for basic authentication and required username and password and then return result

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3//libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net.html#label-Basic+Authentication), you can call a `#basic_auth` method on a `Net::HTTP::Get` object. It requires constructing a `Net::HTTP::Get` object instead of calling `#get` on a `Net::HTTP` object, but this is trivial.